# Using Promise.all to return a value from a function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to return an array that is being built with async calls, something like this:

I want `myArr` in the function that calls `foo()`

```
 function foo(){

    let promiseArray = [];
    let singlePromise;
    let myArr = [];

    for(let node of Nodes){

      singlePromise = getSomePromise(node);
      singlePromise.then(function(result){
        myArr.push(bar(result));  
      });

      promiseArray.push(singlePromise);
    }

    // return Promise.all(promiseArray)? but then I lose myArr
  }
```

So how can I return `myArr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than pushing to `myArr`, push promises that resolve to the values you need:

```
function foo() {
    const promiseArray = [];

    for (const node of Nodes) {
        const singlePromise =
            getSomePromise(node).then(function (result) {
                return bar(result);
            });

        promiseArray.push(singlePromise);
    }

    return Promise.all(promiseArray);
}
```

If you’re using a promise library like [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) (highly recommended), you can even do this:

```
const foo = () =>
    Promise.map(Nodes, node =>
        getSomePromise(node).then(bar)
    );
```

and if `Nodes` is an array:

```
const foo = () =>
    Promise.all(Nodes.map(getSomePromise)).map(bar);
```

Comment: Why do you use const?

Comment: @kuhaku: Prevents modifying variables by accident; encourages a more functional style.

Comment: @kuhaku: Speaking of a more functional style: see edit.

Comment: Is Bluebird as good as https://caolan.github.io/async/ with asynchronicity?

Comment: @kuhaku: Bluebird is way, way better.

Comment: In my actual code, I return an object like `{a: asdf, b: qwer}` in the `singlePromise` callback, but in the resolved value of the promises, I have only one value and not an object, any idea why?

Comment: Oh I see, I get `result` instead of `bar(result);`, but why?

Comment: @kuhaku: I’m not sure why you would. Keep in mind that `.then()` returns a new promise rather than modifying the existing one; you have to push the return value of `then` into the promise array.

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all` will resolve with an array

```
return Promise.all(promiseArray)
  .then(arr){
   // arr is an array
}
```

Comment: But how can I pass `arr` as a return value of `foo`?

Comment: You can't return an array per se. You will have to first resolve the promise and use the array from within. Read more about promises https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise